# Clear Content Assistant

Tags: xtext

I have a grammar rule like

```
MyIdentifier:
    prefix=Prefix ('.' suffix=Suffix)?;

Prefix :
    name=ID
;

Suffix:
    name=ID
;
```

Now I can add some custom Content Proposals by implementing the `completeSuffix_Name` method.

However, there are some default proposals like[image].

How can I get rid of these and show **only** my custom proposals?

Edit: Xtext version 2.10.0

Answer (score 1):

In your customized `DSLProposalProvider` that extends `AbstractDSLProposalProvider`, when overriding a method just **don't** do `super.complete_something` after `acceptor.accept(..)`.

If you want to get rid of keywords, make sure you override `completeKeyword` from `AbstractContentProposalProvider` with an empty implementation. Pay attention to the parameters (different from the `AbstractDSLProposalProvider` functions).

Comment: Are you maybe referring to an older Xtext version? I use Xtext 2.10.0 and I don't have a `AbstractContentProposalProvider` and I also don't find any occurence of `completeKeyword`in my whole workspace.

Comment: I use 2.10 too. Go to your `ui.contentassist` package. You should have an empty class that extends `AbstractDSLProposalProvider`. You can override the methods in this empty class.

Comment: ` completeKeyword`  is in  `AbstractContentProposalProvider` (which  `AbstractDSLProposalProvider` finally extends, just climb up the hierarchy).

Comment: `AbstractDSLProposalProvider` extends `XbaseProposalProvider` extends `AbstractXbaseProposalProvider` extends `XtypeProposalProvider`extends `AbstractXtypeProposalProvider` extends `AbstractJavaBasedContentProposalProvider` extends `AbstractContentProposalProvider`